# Frequencies data table multiple columns

Tags: r, data.table, multiple-columns, frequency

I have a data table like this

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(a= c("a","a","b","b","b"), b= c("a","a","c","c","e"),    c=c("d","d","b","b","b"))
```

I want to **count frequencies** from **all the columns**. I know how to do it one by one, but I want to do it in one instruction because my data has a lot of columns.

Result must be this one:

```
dt[,a1:=.N, by = c("a")]
dt[,a2:=.N, by = c("b")]
dt[,a3:=.N, by = c("c")]
```

Comment: Use a `for()` loop.

Comment: @RichScriven can you show me an example.

Comment: Try `nm1 <- paste0("a", seq_along(dt));for(j in seq_along(dt)){
 dt[, nm1[j] := .N, by = c(names(dt)[j])]
 }`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(a= c("a","a","b","b","b"), 
                 b= c("a","a","c","c","e"),   
                 c=c("d","d","b","b","b"))
#dt
#   a b c
#1: a a d
#2: a a d
#3: b c b
#4: b c b
#5: b e b

l=lapply(seq_along(colnames(dt)), 
         function(i) dt[,eval(colnames(dt)[i]),with=F][, x:=.N,by=eval(colnames(dt)[i])])
#l 
#[[1]]
#   a x
#1: a 2
#2: a 2
#3: b 3
#4: b 3
#5: b 3

#[[2]]
#   b x
#1: a 2
#2: a 2
#3: c 2
#4: c 2
#5: e 1

#[[3]]
#   c x
#1: d 2
#2: d 2
#3: b 3
#4: b 3
#5: b 3


df = as.data.frame(l)

# replacing alternate column names with concatenating "_count" to it
colnames(df)[seq(2,length(colnames(df)),2)]=
 paste0(colnames(df)[seq(1,length(colnames(df)),2)],"_count")

#df
#  a a_count b b_count c c_count
#1 a       2 a       2 d       2
#2 a       2 a       2 d       2
#3 b       3 c       2 b       3
#4 b       3 c       2 b       3
#5 b       3 e       1 b       3
```

Comment: If you eliminate `x :=.N` and just do:`l=lapply(seq_along(colnames(dt)), 
         function(i) dt[,eval(colnames(dt)[i]),with=F][,.N,by=eval(colnames(dt)[i])])` solution is better.